# Custom Newtonsoft.Json serialization of objects in a seperate library

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I want to write a custom json serializer for a controller where when it encounters a non-primitive(excluding string/datetime) it looks in that object for an ID field/property and then instead of serializing the entire object, writes a {ID, Name}(where ID is the value of ID, and Name is the name of the data object) instead.

The purpose behind this is I writing a Cache viewer but the cache items can get huge. I could just take the ID field and ignore the rest in the UI, but then I might have issues with sending way to much data in the response.

I'm having trouble figuring out where I should even start, so excuse this question if its a little to broad.

**Extra Notes:**
The Data Items i need to serialize, are in a separate library, and i don't have access to them, but I am guaranteed that they will all use an ID field. It's ok if I miss a few data-points because they are a non-primitive, non-datetime, non-string field.

This is what i have so far to write only the primitives:

```
public class FieldsOnlyFormatterConfig : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
    {
        public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings settings,
            HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            // Clear the formatters list.
            settings.Formatters.Clear();
            var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();
            // Add a custom media-type formatter.
            settings.Formatters.Add(formatter);
        }


    }

    class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field && (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => true;
            }
            else
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
            }

            return prop;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) What is your code currently doing that is not satisfactory?  2) Can you give a more concrete, minimal example of classes you want to serialize, and how you want the JSON to appear?

Answer (score 0):

So with some more fiddling around I was able to figure out how to accomplish what I wanted.

I changed my custom resolver to detect if my property type is a DataItem, and then set the prop.Converter to use a custom jsonConverter:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field && (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => true;
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DataItem)))
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => true;
                prop.Converter = new DataItemConverter();
            }
            else
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
            }

            return prop;
        }
    }
```

In the custom json converter, on WriteJson I casted the object to a DataItem(a class i knew everything i wanted inhertited from, which has the "id" field im looking for) and then did a few custom writes:

```
class DataItemConverter: JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var di = value as DataItem;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("id");
            writer.WriteValue(di.Id);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
```